# Suppress asyncio runtime errors in Python on exit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm working on a discord bot using discord.py, and am trying to make the bot easy to kill without throwing up a bunch of errors to make it easier to work on further. I have tried all sorts of exception/error suppression methods, such as the Try/Except pass, but to no avail.

```py
import discord,time
try:
    config = open('config.ini','r')
    botToken= config.readline()[7:]
    log_outfile = open('file','w')
    class Client(discord.Client):
        async def on_ready(self):
            print(time.asctime()[11:20] + '| Logged on as {0}'.format(self.user))
            log_outfile.writelines(time.asctime()[11:20] + '| Logged on as {0}\n'.format(self.user))
            log_outfile.flush()


        async def on_message(self, message):
            print(time.asctime()[11:20] + '| Message from {0.author} in server {0.guild} in channel {0.channel}: {0.content}'.format(message))
            
            log_outfile.writelines(time.asctime()[11:20] + '| Message from {0.author} in server {0.guild} in channel {0.channel}: {0.content}\n'.format(message))
            log_outfile.flush()

    botClient = Client()
    try:
        botClient.run(botToken)
    except TimeoutError:
        print('Connection timed out. Please ensure a stable connection for optimal bot functionality.')
    except discord.LoginFailure:
        print("That token didn't work. Try changing the token in config.ini")
        exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
    log_outfile.close()        ##I'm not sure if formatting is right since I just copy-pasted parts of my code so as to not reveal anything.
```

to which, when I ctrl + c, it outputs:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001D08F202790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001D08F202790>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
C:\Bot\Directory
```

Help?

Comment: NEVER close files manually! Open them using the `with` context manager. This also eliminates the need to handle control-c, which is something you never want to do. Try using `await client.start()` inside a coroutine.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I'm still new to making actual functional programs and not just basic autoclickers.